# Htaccess Language Subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to add rules to turn subdomains into a lang parameter, for `en` and `de` only. All other rules are working fine so far, but if I try to access any `de.xyz` or `en.xyz` I got a `Server not found`.

I figured since it works for eliminating the www., it should also let me tackle the subdomains in the same way. I'm not sure if maybe I have to put them in a different order.

Can anybody link me to a solution to this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 

# exclude acp directory
RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - 

RewriteRule ^sitemap(/?)$ index.php?page=Sitemap 

RewriteRule ^imprint(/?)$ index.php?page=Imprint 
RewriteRule ^impressum(/?)$ index.php?page=Imprint 

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/404(/?)$ index.php?page=Error404 

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+?)/([0-9a-z-]+?)/([0-9a-z-]+?)(/?)$ tutorial-redirect.php?category=$1&section=$2&chapter=$3 
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+?)/([0-9a-z-]+?)(/?)$ tutorial-redirect.php?category=$1&section=$2 
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+?)(/?)$ tutorial-redirect.php?category=$1 

# redirect en
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1&lang=en 

# redirect de
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^de\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1&lang=de 

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
# redirect en and de
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(en|de)\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2/$1?lang=%1 [QSA,R,L]
```

Or for rewrite (without redirect):

```
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding the subdomains was a good tip. Tried to add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(en|de)\.(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=%1 [QSA,L]` but only getting error 500 so far.

Comment: `[Tue Dec 15 17:56:54 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` - I assume that means I have created a loop?

Comment: YES! Sorry, I edited the code with test for existing query string lang

Comment: That works for the redirect version, thank you. I was hoping to use the rewrite instead - is there any way to check if that rule has already been executed?

Comment: D'oh! Had tried that, didn't work before. Just had some stuff in the wrong order. Thank you very much!